# MySQL Запрос на оконную функцию в работе

Tags: mysql

Как с этой таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE Operation (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
  duration INT NOT NULL,
  work CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO Operation (time, duration, work)
VALUES
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:33.8', 10, 'a'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:36.7', 10, 'a'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:37.9', 10, 'a'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:41.6', 10, 'b'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:43.0', 10, 'b'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:43.6', 10, 'b'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:44.2', 10, 'b'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:47.5', 10, 'c'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:48.3', 10, 'c'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:50.2', 10, 'a'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:51.0', 10, 'a'),
  ('2020-08-30 17:33:51.6', 10, 'a');
```

Получить данный вывод?

```
time, duration, work
2020-08-30 17:33:33.800,30,a
2020-08-30 17:33:41.600,40,b
2020-08-30 17:33:47.500,20,c
2020-08-30 17:33:50.200,30,a
```

Comment: Я вижу минимум по времени и сумму по продолжительности в неразрывной группе. Т.е. обычный "Gaps and Islands".

Comment: @Akina, написал по такому принципу скрипт, выводит всю таблицу.
SELECT
  MIN(time) AS time, SUM(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY work ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS duration, work
FROM
  Operation
GROUP BY duration, work, time;

Comment: Я же дал точное название!